# How to talk to imap server in shell via Openssl using imap compression?

Tags: scripting, imap, deflate, rfc

I’m having some problems at understanding [rfc4978](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4978).
As I understand it, everything is compressed after the server returns`OK`including the command names. However it seems I misunderstood several things *(because`[Gmail]/sfgs`isn’t renamed and obviously the file isn’t sent)*.

```
 $ cat deflatecommands /dev/stdin | socat - OPENSSL:imap.googlemail.com:993,compress=none
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT APPENDLIMIT=35882577 LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS
a001 OK myus.tyer@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
a002 OK Success
2016/04/28 21:47:03 socat[16204.25769803872] E SSL_write(): Broken pipe
```

where deflatecommands contains :

```
a001 LOGIN myus.tyer mypassord
a002 COMPRESS DEFLATE
xÚK400VrõsôuUPŠvÏMÌÌ‰Õ/NK/VBp+@‰— Ô)
```

which uncompressed gives :

```
a001 LOGIN myus.tyer mypassord
a002 COMPRESS DEFLATE
a003 RENAME "[Gmail]/sfgs" "[Gmail]/xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Of course`deflatecommands`uses`crfl`line endings in both uncompressed and compressed parts.
`deflatecommands`is created with :

```
$ openssl zlib a003 > a003.zlib
$ cat a001 a002 a003.zlib > defaltecommands
```

Comment: A last thing due to the speed of my connection, nothing is sent before`a002 OK Success`if printed on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work.  All three commands will be sent in one packet, but the server will likely flush the input buffer when enabling compression.  You will probably need a pause between compress and the compressed command.  Also, if there is a CRLF in the compressed part, that will be a problem as well.  You'll need to edit the file in binary mode and make sure there is not a cleartext CRLF.

Comment: @Max : There’s no uncompressed ᴄʀʟꜰ in`a003.zlib`. And again, not any compressed bytes are send before GImap returned`OK Success`.

Comment: If you're just catting them in, they are going out before any responses are received. Otherwise update your question with what you're doing :)

Comment: @Max : Ok, I now use a one liner script do delay between cat commands *(while steel piping)*. But it would add too much confusion to my question *(and for course in reality I want to send lot of data that require compression which means not just a rename command)*. The point is still the server close the connection as soon as it receive the first bytes compressed with`openssl zlib`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to talk IMAP from shell? While I applaud your choice of heavy pipelining which IMAP indeed supports, there's a limit to the allowed pipelineable commands. `LOGIN` is safe, in theory, but I would not personally enqueue anything right after it without waiting for its result (and this is the moment where your naive shell pipe will hit its limits). `COMPRESS DEFLATE` is **not** safe to pipeline by any means because the server has to switch on transparent compression. In many languages, this usually involves a flush of the network buffer(s) on various layers.

Why are you complicating the whole matter with activation of the `COMPRESS` extension? It is by no means necessary, and it won't really save you any measurable amount of bytes in this particular scenario.

Comment: `It is by no means necessary, and it won't really save you any measurable amount of bytes in this particular scenario.` **It’s wrong !** I’m planning sending something  Gb large but that give 50Mb once deflate compressed. It is too large to be done though a traditional e‑mail client and would take too much time on 243Kb/s *(upload speed)* internet connection if uncompressed. Please don’t assume I’m trying to solve the wrong problem . http://stackoverflow.com/q/14959461/2284570 *(and in fact I now use a small shell script for waiting sever responses before continuing)*.

Comment: Good luck trying to save something "GB large" into GMail. Anyway, you chose to use shell scripting, well, you'll have to deal with the induced pain.